# jssor Slider add Video

Tags: jssor

I would like to add a video inside my current image slider. I don't want only video to play but a mix of video and images. I've been able to get the video to play but I need to add the pause, play and stop controllers as well as make that slide last longer than the other slides. Can anyone please help me?

http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/

```
<!-- Insert Slideshow -->

<div id="slideshowwrapper">
  <div id="slider1_container" style="left: 0px; top: 5px; width: 687px; height: 324px; overflow: visible; position: relative;">

    <!-- Slides Container -->

    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 687px; height: 324px; overflow: hidden;">
<div><a u="image" href="http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/special-offers/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Halloween-show.png" /></a></div>
<div><a u="image" href="http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/special-offers/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/After-Summer.png" /></a></div>
<div><video style="width="687px" height="324px" autoplay>
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/PiratesSeaDragon_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/PiratesSeaDragon.ogv" type="video/ogg" pHideControls="0" />
</video></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jssor Slider supports youtube video.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.player.ytiframe.min.js"></script>
```

You can put a video player in any slide in following format:

```
<div>
 <div u="player" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 640px; height: 390px; overflow: hidden;">
   <!-- iframe in ebay page is not allowed, youtube iframe video is not supported for ebay listing -->
   <iframe pHandler="ytiframe" pHideControls="0" width="640" height="390" style="z-index: 0;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H7jtC8vjXw8?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&fs=1&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
   <!-- play cover begin (optional, can remove play cover) -->
   <div u="cover" class="videoCover" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #000; background-image: url(../img/play.png); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: .4; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 1;"></div>
   <!-- play cover end -->
   <!-- close button begin (optional, can remove close button) -->
   <style>
      .closeButton { background-image: url(../img/close.png); }
      .closeButton:hover { background-position: -30px 0px; }
   </style>
   <div u="close" class="closeButton" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 1px; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: #000; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 2;"></div>
   <!-- close button end -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Downloaded and included ytiframe.min.js, copied your code and just changed the youtube url (also removed close button)... What should I do?

Comment: Found a solution: youtube video must be with "src" attribute, not "url"

Comment: @jssor as per today, how to use in the right way jssor.player.ytiframe.min.js with jssor 28.1.0 ? It seems that the ytiframe lib's abandoned or not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

and add

```
//fetch and initialize youtube players
$JssorPlayer$.$FetchPlayers(document.body);
```

Comment: What @RohitGupta said. This answer has been flagged already and is showing up in the Low Quality Posts review queue, so lacking any explanation, it is at risk of being deleted and lost.